# Determine which nuget.config file is used by nuget

Tags: .net, nuget, dotnet-cli

Nuget has [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied) for locating the `nuget.config` file to be used.

In a large/complex monorepo the file will not necessarily be at the workspace/solution "root".

Is there a shell command to determine which `nuget.config` file nuget has selected and will use for nuget operations?

(The closest thing I've found is `dotnet nuget list source`, but that doesn't tell me which file was selected.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find a single command to answer your question directly. But when running `dotnet restore -f -v n`, it gives me the following output:

```
Build started 22.08.2022 08:58:38.
     1>Project "C:\source\temp\NuGetTest2\NuGetTest2.sln" on node 1 (Restore target(s)).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
       _GetAllRestoreProjectPathItems:
         Determining projects to restore...
       Restore:
         Restoring packages for C:\source\temp\NuGetTest2\src\Test\Test.csproj...
         Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: C:\source\temp\NuGetTest2\src\Test\obj\project.assets.json
         Restored C:\source\temp\NuGetTest2\src\Test\Test.csproj (in 373 ms).

         NuGet Config files used:
             C:\source\temp\NuGetTest2\src\Test\NuGet.Config
             C:\source\temp\NuGetTest2\src\NuGet.Config
             C:\source\temp\NuGetTest2\NuGet.Config
             C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
             C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

         Feeds used:
             https://apiC.nuget.org/v3/index.json
     1>Done Building Project "C:\source\temp\NuGetTest2\NuGetTest2.sln" (Restore target(s)).
```

Since `apiC` gets used, I'd assume that the order of the output is equivalent to the precedence. These are my `NuGet.Config` files:

- `NuGet.Config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="NuGetA" value="https://apiA.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

- `src\NuGet.Config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="NuGetB" value="https://apiB.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

- `src\Test\NuGet.Config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="NuGetC" value="https://apiC.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Nice analysis, thanks! For those using bash: `dotnet restore -v n | sed -n '/NuGet Config files used:/,/nuget.config/p' | tail -n-1 | xargs printf '%s\n'`

Comment: Is there a way to determine which files will be used without actually doing a restore with logging?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer explains the approach.

If you want a bash one-liner:

```bash
dotnet restore -v n | sed -n '/NuGet Config files used:/,/nuget.config/p' | tail -n-1 | xargs printf '%s\n'
```